# Unable to cast object of type nullable(of object) using entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently using a scenario of MVC 4 WebAPI w Entity Framework database first modelling. Within my apicontroller it is giving me an error of:

> An error has occurred. 
>   Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[VB$AnonymousType_4`2[System.Nullable`1[System.Guid],System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CK5.Airline]],VB$AnonymousType_5`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Guid]]]'
>   to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CK5.Airline]'.
>   </ExceptionMessage>
>   <ExceptionType>System.InvalidCastException</ExceptionType>
>   <StackTrace> at  lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] ) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass13.<GetExecutor>b__c(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object
>   instance, Object[] arguments) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1
>   func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

```
    Public Class AirlineController
            Inherits ApiController

            ' GET api/Airline
            Function GetAirlines() As IEnumerable(Of Airline)
                Using db As New DefaultEntities
                    Return From p In db.Airlines.AsEnumerable Order By {p.Name} Group By ParentID = p.ParentID Into parentIDGroup = Group Select New With {.ParentID = ParentID}
                End Using
            End Function
End Class
```

Within my entity model object the ParentID is a nullable(of guid) type and I believe causing the problem. I've had this working before using a Linq2Sql scenerio, but with the update, this is giving me a problem. I don't believe it's a problem with the web api structure, just w entity framework. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I am not a VB.NET expert but from what I see you are returning an IEnumerable of an anonymous type (which I believe is not allowed anyways) but your method says that you will be returning IEnumerable(Of Airline) so the VB is trying to cast the actual result to the one you declared and fails.

Comment: i fixed it.  1) For some reason EF doesn't like to use the statement Using db as New DBContext, it closes the connection before use I think. 2) I'm not sure why either, but it also doesn't like using lambda statements. So it didn't like the Order By or Group By statement. I'll have to look in to that. 3) problem was a bit unrelated, but as this was being a database first EF, I had also put in the globabl.asax this statement: Database.SetInitializer(New DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges(Of DefaultEntities)()). Thinking it would update the model or database based on changes. It lied to me. =/

Comment: I don't think this statements are accurate. You should using "Using" in order to not leak connections. OrderBy and GroupBy with lambdas should be perfectly fine. If you were using DatabaseFirst the initializer will not work since the database will not have additional data needed to tell if the database changed or not. Since you seem to be fine with dropping the database - why don't you drop the database and then have it create by your app? This way the initializer should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed it. 1) For some reason EF doesn't like to use the statement Using db as New DBContext, it closes the connection before use I think. 2) I'm not sure why either, but it also doesn't like using lambda statements. So it didn't like the Order By or Group By statement. I'll have to look in to that. 3) problem was a bit unrelated, but as this was being a database first EF, I had also put in the globabl.asax this statement: Database.SetInitializer(New DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges(Of DefaultEntities)()). Thinking it would update the model or database based on changes. It lied to me. =/